# How many app registrations do I need in a microserice architecture

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-identity-platform

I have a microservice architecture, where one Single Page Application accesses three different APIs:

[image]

I am securing those APIs via the Microsoft Identity Platform and therefore I also need service principals.
My first approach matches with all the examples I found on blogs or in the MS docs.
In this case I have one app registration for the client app and three additional ones for the APIs:

[image]

This has the following impact:

1. Each API has its own audience.
2. I get four service principals for each application.
3. I get three different places where I have to administrate the user assignments to roles. (for example: User A can read assets from API A etc...)

This works, but comes also with some problems:

1. The other admins that are managing which user is allowed to do what are confused about three different places they have to assign roles. It would be nicer to have one central place.
2. The roles of the users are not placed in the ID tokens, because only roles of the client application would go there... but I do not want to assign permissions in the client app again.
3. If API A wants to call API B or C, I need two access tokens for other APIs.

This lead me to a second idea:

[image]

Here I have one registration for all 3 APIs. This already solves problem 1 and problem 2. But it also gives me a strange feeling, because I never found other people doing so.
Also my ID tokens are not telling me the roles, so to fix this, I could even go another step further to a single app registration for everything:

[image]

Now one registration exposes an API and consumes this API also. Something what is possible and seems to solve my problems. I even get all roles for the users in my ID tokens AND in my access tokens now.

However, this is contradictive to all other examples I found.

1. Which disadvantages does the last solution have?
2. Which of the three approaches should I chose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which disadvantages does the last solution have?

One thing that comes to my mind is that you want API A to be able to edit data in e.g. MS Graph API, so you give it the app permission to Read/Write Directory data.
Now with the shared app registration this permission has also been given to API B and API C.

So the principle of least privilege may be violated in *the second and third options*.
But it does make it easier to manage those APIs as you noticed.

The third option does open up the door for the user to acquire access tokens to any APIs that you might want to call on behalf of the current user from your APIs.
So if you wanted to API A to edit a user through MS Graph API on behalf of the user, you'd have to require the read/write users delegated permission (scope) for your app.
This would allow the user to acquire this token from your front-end as well, even though that is not intended.
Now they would not be able to do anything they wouldn't otherwise be able to do since the token's permissions are limited based on the user's permissions, so this might not be a significant disadvantage.

> Which of the three approaches should I chose?

As with many things, it depends :)

If you want absolute least privilege for your services, option 1.

If you want easier management, I'd go with option 3 instead of 2.
There was that one thing I mentioned above about option 3 but that does not allow privilege escalation.

Comment: Mhh... then maybe last option is best for me. I do not need to call any MS apis. My application is absolutely independent of microsoft products. I just like the identity platform, so I am happy I can go with option 1... I just need SSO for the users in our company.

Comment: Ahh, another thing is if you wanted to limit that only API B can call API C. Then you'd need to use the first option as well.

Comment: Okay, but lets say API A is the only one that wants to call the graph on behalf of the user. In this case I would have to use the On Behalf flow, to exchange a token issued for API A with another access token for the graph on behalf of the calling user? This is what you meant in your first sentense of the answer, right?

Comment: Actually I was referring to _application permissions_ so client credentials flow, which would allow the API to call the Graph API as itself, with no user info in the token. But the first part can be applied to the on-behalf-of scenario as well. OBO is just more constrained as it'll require a user to be present and the token's permissions will be limited to user's permissions.

Comment: Okay, so with client credential flow you mean, that the API itself has the client secret for the client application (that also has the scopes of the api added) but also could have the graph added with some permissions. So in this way the API itself could receive an access token to access the graph (without any user involved)?

Comment: Yes, with that flow the app sends Azure AD only its client id + secret (or it can use a certificate) and says what API it wants to call. It then gets an access token with only the app's info in it. Delegated permissions/scopes don't apply here, only application permissions.